# Rabbitmq dead letter spring integration xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

hi am trying to achieve dead letter exchange in spring integration XML so the scenario is **AAA exchange** binded **BBB queue** if BBB queue getting failed in some scenario like **lister threw exception** i want to navigate exception to Dead exchange queue to store message below is the code

created sample project

main.java

```
package com.spring.rabbit.first.deadletter;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- Spring configuration -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.rabbit.first" />
    <context:mbean-export default-domain="com.spring.rabbit.first.deadletter" />

    <!-- RabbitMQ common configuration -->

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        username="guest" password="guest" port="5672" virtual-host="/" host="localhost" />


    <!-- <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"/> -->
    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <!-- Queues -->

    <rabbit:queue id="springQueue" name="spring.queue"
        auto-delete="true" durable="false" />

    <rabbit:listener-container
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" advice-chain="retryAdvice">
        <rabbit:listener queues="BBBqueue" ref="messageListener" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.spring.rabbit.first.deadletter.MessageHandler" />



    <bean id="retryAdvice"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean">
        <property name="messageRecoverer" ref="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer" />
        <property name="retryOperations" ref="retryTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer" />


    <bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
        <property name="backOffPolicy">
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                <property name="initialInterval" value="2000" />
                <property name="multiplier" value="10.0" />
                <property name="maxInterval" value="30000" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="retryPolicy">
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <rabbit:topic-exchange name="AAAqueue">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="BBBqueue" pattern="" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>


    <rabbit:queue name="BBBqueue">
        <rabbit:queue-arguments>
            <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="XXX.dead.letter"></entry>
            <entry key="x-message-ttl" value="10000" value-type="java.lang.Long" />
        </rabbit:queue-arguments>
    </rabbit:queue>


    <!-- dead letter -->

    <rabbit:topic-exchange name="XXX.dead.letter">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="XXX.dead.letter.queue" pattern=""></rabbit:binding>
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>

    <rabbit:queue name="XXX.dead.letter.queue"></rabbit:queue>



</beans>
```

Message handler

```
package com.spring.rabbit.first.deadletter;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;

public class MessageHandler implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
        System.out.println("Text: " + new String(message.getBody()));

        message = null;
        if (message == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
}
```

Messagesender

```
package com.spring.rabbit.first.deadletter;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperation;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@ManagedResource
public class MessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate template;

    @ManagedOperation
    public void send(String text) {
        send("amq.fanout", "NDPAR.SPRING.JAVA", text);
    }

    @ManagedOperation
    public void send(String exchange, String key, String text) {
        template.convertAndSend(exchange, key, text);
    }
}
```

output:

```
23:57:33.753 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer - Received message: (Body:'[B@1c18b12a(byte[4])' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=null, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=BBBqueue, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-yPBzkqcKH2zX2IjWqT20wg, consumerQueue=BBBqueue])
23:57:33.777 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=0
Received message: (Body:'[B@1c18b12a(byte[4])' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=null, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=BBBqueue, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-yPBzkqcKH2zX2IjWqT20wg, consumerQueue=BBBqueue])
Text: send
23:58:06.952 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy - Sleeping for 2000
23:58:08.953 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=1
23:58:08.953 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=1
Received message: (Body:'[B@1c18b12a(byte[4])' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=null, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=BBBqueue, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-yPBzkqcKH2zX2IjWqT20wg, consumerQueue=BBBqueue])
Text: send
23:58:12.888 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy - Sleeping for 20000
23:58:39.016 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=2
23:58:39.016 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=2
Received message: (Body:'[B@1c18b12a(byte[4])' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=null, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=BBBqueue, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-yPBzkqcKH2zX2IjWqT20wg, consumerQueue=BBBqueue])
Text: send
23:58:42.391 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=3
23:58:42.391 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry failed last attempt: count=3
23:58:42.393 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1] WARN org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - 
Retries exhausted for message (Body:'[B@1c18b12a(byte[4])' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=null, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=BBBqueue,
 receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-yPBzkqcKH2zX2IjWqT20wg, consumerQueue=BBBqueue])
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:780)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:700)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

But still i did't see any message in dead letter queue.is am missing anything??
kindly help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your `XXX-channel` and adapter are supposed to do, but you need to add a `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` to the retry advice factory bean (in the `messageRecoverer` property).

The default recover just logs that retries are exhausted and discards the message.

**EDIT**

Here is a custom `MessageRecoverer` that publishes a failed message from queue `A` to a queue named `A.dlq` - the queue and binding are declared automatically, as needed.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014-2016 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.retry.MessageRecoverer;

public class AutoConfiguringRepublishMessageRecoverer implements MessageRecoverer {

    public static final String X_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE = "x-exception-stacktrace";

    public static final String X_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "x-exception-message";

    public static final String X_ORIGINAL_EXCHANGE = "x-original-exchange";

    public static final String X_ORIGINAL_ROUTING_KEY = "x-original-routingKey";

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private final RabbitTemplate errorTemplate;

    private final RabbitAdmin admin;

    private final String deadLetterExchangeName = "DLX";

    private final DirectExchange deadletterExchange = new DirectExchange(this.deadLetterExchangeName);

    private boolean initialized;

    public AutoConfiguringRepublishMessageRecoverer(RabbitTemplate errorTemplate) {
        this.errorTemplate = errorTemplate;
        this.admin = new RabbitAdmin(errorTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public void recover(Message message, Throwable cause) {
        if (!this.initialized) {
            initialize();
        }
        Map<String, Object> headers = message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        headers.put(X_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE, getStackTraceAsString(cause));
        headers.put(X_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, cause.getCause() != null ? cause.getCause().getMessage() : cause.getMessage());
        headers.put(X_ORIGINAL_EXCHANGE, message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedExchange());
        headers.put(X_ORIGINAL_ROUTING_KEY, message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedRoutingKey());

        String dlqName = message.getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue() + ".dlq";
        if (this.admin.getQueueProperties(dlqName) == null) {
            bindDlq(dlqName);
        }
        this.errorTemplate.send(this.deadLetterExchangeName, dlqName, message);
        if (this.logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
            this.logger.warn("Republishing failed message to " + dlqName);
        }
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.admin.declareExchange(this.deadletterExchange);
        this.initialized = true;
    }

    private void bindDlq(String dlqName) {
        Queue dlq = new Queue(dlqName);
        this.admin.declareQueue(dlq);
        this.admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(dlq).to(this.deadletterExchange).with(dlqName));
    }

    private String getStackTraceAsString(Throwable cause) {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter, true);
        cause.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply is there any example to over come this issue

Comment: Simply `<property name="messageRecoverer"><bean class="o.s.a.r.retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer" /></property>`

Comment: Your configuration works fine for me, as long as I publish to exchange `AAAqueue` with no routing key. This is because the same routing key for the original publish is used for the DLX/DLQ. If you want all message to go to the DLQ, regardless of original routing key, use `<rabbit:binding queue="XXX.dead.letter.queue" pattern="#" />`.

Comment: I don't know what version you are using - the latest is 1.7.0. However, you should remove the `-1.0` from your schema `...spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd"` so you use the latest schema version from the jar - use `...spring-rabbit.xsd"`.

Comment: thx for reply am getting msg in dead letter but  want to store exception  i can see those information  delivery_mode: 1
headers: 
x-death: 
count: 1
reason: rejected
queue: BBBqueue
time: 1487210093
exchange: 
routing-keys: BBBqueue

Comment: RabbitMQ doesn't support that via message rejection - you have to publish it yourself for that. Spring AMQP provides the [RepublishMessageRecoverer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_change_history.html#_republishmessagerecoverer) for that - it adds information, including the stack trace, to headers. [Javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/index.html?org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/retry/RepublishMessageRecoverer.html).

Comment: thx u so much for information.is there anyway to bind  queue and routing dynamically in any exchange  after republishMessageRecoverer

Comment: It doesn't currently support dynamic routing. You would have to create your own version (copy the standard one), use a `RabbitAdmin` to create exchange/queue/binding as necessary and route to the exchange with the appropriate routing key.

Comment: in existing we had A,B,C upto Z queue  so now planning to store all exception  after recover.so idea is 
to create a direct exchange to bind like if A queue occur error  the plan is to create A1 routing to A1 queue to store exception.
is it possible to implement after recover.if yes suggest some idea or else any suggestion  ??

Comment: I edited my answer with a custom recoverer that does something like you asked.

Comment: Thanks for coding I Wil test the  scenario and let u know

Comment: I just fixed a small bug (`initialized = true;`).

Comment: thx u so much for ur help and example its working fine my scenario